# How to change JobParameters in Spring Batch during execution?

Tags: spring-boot, parameters, spring-batch, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a working job execution, which sets a few job parameters at the beginning, and executes the job launcher with it.

I can also read properties from job parameters in the steps:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name
```

But is it possible, to add more parameters to this in a step? Like in a Processor?

So when it comes to Writer, it will have an extra parameter.

If yes, then how?

Thanks!

Comment: A job parameter cannot be added afterwards, it does not make sense to me. What are you trying to achieve? Dynamic infos can be added in the job execution context and used as required in subsequent steps. Have you considered using the execution context for your use case?

Comment: Do you want to pass parameters from Reader/Processor to Writer ?